# css-loader returns undefined on importing css file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, css-modules, webpack-loader

I have a css file named App.css which has css like

```
.abcd {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

I am importing this and using in my react app like

```
import styles from './App.css'
console.log("style", styles) // it gives object. 

<div className={"ui equal width grid " + styles.abcd}>
</div>
```

Here `styles.abcd` is showing `undefined` but when I console `styles` it gives object with that classname on array.. I dont know what is missing here.

My webpack conf looks like:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    },
},
```

I have also tried

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
},
```

Nothing is working. Why is it giving `undefined` ?

Comment: Have you looked in your bundle to see what webpack is producing?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with "ui equal width grid "

Comment: you should import your css like this if its a file `import styles from './App.css'`

Comment: what if  `<div className={"ui equal width grid abcd"}>
</div>` ?

Comment: @sdgluck I get an object with class name when I console my styles variable. but when I try to use its  attribute `styles.abcd` , its giving me undefined

Comment: @mthrsj that will no locally scope my css

Comment: Please, include the `console.log` of `styles` in your question

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem answered here: [CSS Modules class names undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561983/css-modules-class-names-undefined)

> In the docs, it's mentioned that you have to name the file as follow :
>
> [name].module.css
>
> Try renaming the file to : Catalog.module.css and import it like this :
>
> import styles from './Catalog.module.css';

In your case you should name it App.module.css and import as such.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is :

```
import styles from './App.css'
console.log("style", styles) // it gives object. 

<div className={"ui equal width grid " + styles.abcd}>
</div>
```

Here it should have been :

```
<div className={`ui equal width grid ${styles.abcd}`}>
```

Comment: Both represent the same string in a different format.