# CSS Modules class names undefined

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules

I try to use css modules in my project. I'm using latest Create React App with react-scripts version 2.1.8. 
In the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet) it says I can add CSS Modules, and i dont have to do eject script.

I tried to do the same way, but my styles are empty and classes are undefined.
Here is the code for one of my components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Catalog.css';

class Catalog extends Component{

render() {
    console.log('styles.catalog '+ styles.catalog); //returns: styles.catalog undefined.
    return (
      <div className={styles.catalog}> //returns: <div>
        ...
      </div>
    )
}
```

Catalog.css:

```
.catalog {
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Did you double check the `path` of your css module ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet), it's mentioned that you have to name the file as follow :

> [name].module.css

Try renaming the file to : `Catalog.module.css` and import it like this :

```
import styles from './Catalog.module.css';
```

Comment: If you are using `typed-css-modules` also you have to use `.module.css`

Answer (score 0):

It's also not recommended to use like catalog-v2.module.css. Instead it'd work if the name of the file is like catalogV2.module.css

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer in case someone else ends up with the same problem as me. My problem was a case sensitivity issue. Apparently the styles still worked when I loaded the file "../**i**nputTextField.scss" when it should have loaded with uppercase I from "./**I**nputTextField.scss"

Somehow it still "cached" the styles or something because the main style worked when doing changes but if I added a style to the component like "style.inverted" and then added that class to the scss file it didn't recognise it and it became undefined.